# Gitlab CICD pipeline pytest - No module named 'main'. Passes locally but not in pipeline

Tags: python, unit-testing, gitlab, gitlab-ci, cicd

Importing functions from another file causes the CICD pipeline to break for some reason. The odd thing is that it passed on the command line for me. Running `pytest` in the project directory passes with no issue. For some reason the pipeline fails and I can't figure out why. Could there be a pathing issue or maybe something I need to include in the yml file?

```
ProjectA
├── .gitlab-ci.yml
├── README.md
├── setup.py
├── pyproject.toml
└── src
    ├──  __init__.py
    ├── test
    │   └── test_cleaning.py
    └── main
        ├──  __init__.py
        └── cleaning  
            ├── test.txt 
            ├──  __init__.py
            └── clean_txt.py
```

This is the test I'm running:

```
from main.cleaning.clean_txt import clean as ctxt

def test_clean_txt(self):
   self.assertEqual(type(ctxt("src/test/test.txt")), list)
   self.assertEqual(ctxt("src/test/test.txt"), self.result)
```

Current gitlab-ci.yml:

```
image: python:3.10.9

before_script:
  - pip install --upgrade pip
  - pip install pytest

stages:
- unit

unit-tests:
  stage: unit
  image: python:3.10.9
  script:
    - pytest -v
  allow_failure: true
```

The Error given by the CICD pipeline in gitlab:

```
ERRORS ====================================
__________________ ERROR collecting src/test/test_cleaning.py __________________
ImportError while importing test module '/builds/jtmcmah/document-text-extraction/src/test/test_cleaning.py'.
Hint: make sure your test modules/packages have valid Python names.
Traceback:
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/importlib/__init__.py:126: in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
src/test/test_cleaning.py:1: in <module>
    from main.cleaning.clean_txt import clean as ctext
E   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'main'
```

Comment: from src.main.cleaning.clean_txt import clean as ctxt ?

Comment: @mrxra I did try that but it causes the tests to fail locally and in the pipeline with a no module named "src". The current set up passes on VScode but not in the pipeline.

Comment: what is your working directory in VScode? how do you run pytest locally?

Comment: ''cd projectA' and then type 'pytest' into the command line. Then it runs all the tests and says it passes.

Comment: _src_ is part of your module hierarchy, so it should be `from src.main.cleaning.clean_txt import clean as ctxt`, which seems to work in gitlab (which executes pytest in your projectA directory)....again: what is your working directory in VScode? how to you launch pytest in **VSCode**?